# 500 Internal Server Error App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm following a tutorial [HERE](https://github.com/alexeyza/startup-programming/blob/master/resources/tutorials/app%20engine%20java%20shoutout.md) to deploy a basic app. When I deploy on Eclipse it says Deployment completed successfully but on the browser it says:

Error:  Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

I used the same link on another computer and it's the same.

I have java 7 & JRE 1.7 on windows 7

**Error details:**

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Persistent class "Class main.Shout does not seem      

to have been enhanced. You may want to rerun the enhancer and check for

errors    in the output." has no table in the database, but the operation 

requires it.    Please check the specification of the MetaData for this   

class.

at   

org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException   

(NucleusJDOHelper.java:519)

at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute (JDOQuery.java:230)

at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService (index_jsp.java:61)

at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service (HttpJspBase.java:97)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:717)

at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:511)

at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle (ServletHandler.java:390)

at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle 

(SecurityHandler.java:216)

at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle (SessionHandler.java:182)

at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle (ContextHandler.java:765)
```

Comment: You might want to google that error message to find more information about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Engine, JDO, and equals/hashCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641697/google-app-engine-jdo-and-equals-hashcode)